# How do I start minikube with containerd instead of docker?

Tags: minikube, containerd

How do I start minikube with containerd instead of default docker ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following command:

```
minikube start --container-runtime=containerd --cni=cilium
```

Here, Cilium (the Container Networking Interface) is an agent running on all cluster nodes and servers in your environment. It provides networking, security, and observability to the workloads running on that node. Workloads can be containerized or running natively on the system.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this (from gvisor site)

```
minikube start --vm-driver="kvm2" --container-runtime=containerd      --docker-opt containerd=/var/run/containerd/containerd.sock --docker-env="http_proxy=x.x.x.x:8080" --docker-env="https_proxy=x.x.x.x:8080" start
```